# Partition of $[a,b]$ such that $f(x)$ is within $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ on each subinterval.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on [a, b].
Show that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an ordered list of points $$x_0=a<x_1<x_2<...<x_n=b$$ such that the set $$E_k= \{f(x)|x \in [x_{k-1},x_k]\}$$ satisfies $$sup(E_k)-inf(E_k)< \epsilon$$ for $k=1,...,n$.

My attempt was starting with point a, we can find smallest $\delta_1$ such $f(a+\delta_1)$ equals to $f(a)+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ or $f(a)-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, whichever comes first given that f is continuous. Thus, the interval $[a, a+ \delta_1 ]$ satisfies the desired sup-inf condition. Then we can continue the construction off of point $a+\delta_1$ and get a set of $\{\delta_{i}\}$. Then I am stuck on how to show that the the set is finite such that we can reach point b in finite partitions. Any opinion on the viability of this approach? In retrospect, this seems a bit brute-forced and a lot of complications would arise (what I have now is mega-hand-wavy) in the end, so I am wondering if there would be a better approach to this?

Comment: Do you know some things about uniform continuity ?

Comment: Now I do! It does render this problem trivial. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I am going to assume that this is an introductory problem, and that you haven't yet been introduced to the concept of *uniform continuity*, which would render this problem trivial.  (If you can use the fact that $ f $ is uniformly continuous on $ [a,b] $, that is the easy, correct solution.)

If you haven't yet learned of uniform continuity and want to write a proof "from scratch", your approach seems reasonable.  You are also correct in noting that it is not "obvious" that the $ \delta_i $ that you chose will reach $ b $ in a finite number of steps.  We can proceed by contradiction.  Suppose you don't reach $ b $.  Then you end up with a sequence of points $ x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots $, with $ x_1 < x_2 < x_3 < \ldots < x^* = \lim x_i \leq b $.  Now you can demonstrate that $ f $ is discontinuous at $ x^* $, which is a contradiction.  If you want a hint about how to show discontinuity at $ x^* $, let me know, but give it a try yourself first.

Comment: It turned out that I missed the recorded lecture on uniform continuity, and this was the on problem on the pset that really asks about the idea so I didn't notice earlier. I would guess that it was my prof's intention to use uniform continuity to solve this. Thanks a lot for your help!